# Fetching and Storing third-party site via PHP and curl on server-side 

Tags: php, curl

For some reason I need to process PHP behind the scenes but not using AJAX (I know that might sound silly to you).  I need this since I am getting the content dynamically through another page loading.
By using PHP's curl functions I can get the login page of a website inside my `1.php` file. But then I use javascript to set form values and hit login and it takes me to the site url (not already localhost/1.php). So the question is: I need to somehow store the content of the page that I am redirected and retrieve it .

Comment: Don't let us ask for specifics. You want an answer you provide the details.

Comment: When it should be processed? There must be 'start-point' for processing ! Some date, some call, some trigger...

Comment: What is the background process doing? Nominally, how long does it take to complete?

Comment: Ok.I login the site . Where I am redirected to an arbitrary url which let say is happening in the 1.php  and from 2.php I am detecting what contents I have in the 1.php file

Comment: @user1204905 - I think your addendum is too abstract to add any extra light. What _exactly_ is the process doing? (Also, it is better to edit your question than to answer questions here, so it is clearer for new readers).

Comment: (In general, you could consider a process kicked off by cron, or maybe something like Gearman, which works very well with PHP)

Comment: Do you need more details for my qestion ? It is still unanswered .

Answer (score 0):

The impression i got was that, you have a resource intensive process, which would perform some action in *background* , while user still interacts whit the page.

I actually would make more sense to do this with some sort of service ( as shell script or standalone application ), but it is possible to do with php: you would need to fork <sup>[[1]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) [[2]](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/3)</sup> the process. Just don' forget to check, if one such process is already running on the system.

It actually works pretty well in combination with XHR (also know as AJAX by marketing department), because you can kick off the process with a request, and then repeatedly check the status .. and then collect the data, when status is "done".

Answer (score 0):

Since we're all taking stabs in the dark, here's what I think you're trying to do (let me know if I'm way off):

You have a site (let's call it `userfriendly.org`) and you are trying to add an interface of some kind to another site (we'lll call this site `mean-corp.com`).  Essentially, when you load the page, you use curl to fetch some of the data from `mean-corp.com` so that your users can login and get some info but without having to deal with their site (maybe it's ugly, maybe it just fits really well into your site, whatever).

You are able to get to the site okay to get whatever initial data you need, but when you try to pass in the user login and password to actually get their info, it's redirecting back to the login URL for the site.

Long story short, you are trying to make a front-to-back web service for another site, but you're running into hiccups with redirects and whatnot?

Am I totally off?  If not, I've made similar attempts in the past for my own nobel reasons,and I could pass along some tips as I'm sure others can.

But if I'm totally off, sorry for the distraction.

Comment: Yes I can get the initial value inside my page (lets say from my index.php file) but when I enter submit it takes me to your mentioned mean-corp.com/you-are-logged-in (I want agian be inside  index.php file to get the content that is currently in mean-corp.com/you-are-logged-in page) .  I think you understood me correctly .  So tell me what is the solution you came up ?